# Polymer equivalent to ng-show?

Tags: angularjs, polymer, polymer-1.0

Is the a polymer equivalent for `ng-show`?  Here's a snippet example of what I'm trying to convert:

```
<h1>Greeting</h1>
<div ng-show="authenticated">
    <p>The ID is {{controller.greeting.id}}</p>
    <p>The content is {{controller.greeting.content}}</p>
</div>
<div  ng-show="!authenticated">
    <p>Login to see your greeting</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dom-if` is not necessary here. Simply use `$=` (attribute binding) to add/remove `hidden` attribute.

```
<style>
[hidden] {
    display:none;
}
</style>

<h1>Greeting</h1>
<div hidden$=[[!authenticated]]>
    <p>The ID is {{controller.greeting.id}}</p>
    <p>The content is {{controller.greeting.content}}</p>
</div>
<div hidden$=[[authenticated]]>
    <p>Login to see your greeting</p>
</div>
```

Use `dom-if` to make decisions about blocks of code that you don't want to be rendered, not just hidden.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could use [**`dom-if`**](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates#dom-if) to conditionally keep required HTML in  DOM tree. `properties` should be defined there in `properties` of component.

```
<template is="dom-if" if="{{authenticated}}">
   <p>The ID is {{controller.greeting.id}}</p>
   <p>The content is {{controller.greeting.content}}</p>
</template>
<template is="dom-if" if="{{!authenticated}}">
   <p>Login to see your greeting</p>
</template>
```

Comment: dom-if equivalent to ng-if!

Comment: even though i am returning true and false but everytime it is showing first template. weather value of authenticated is true or false

Comment: @Rahul can you check the `authenticated` value you're retrieving is in `Boolean` format, because `'true'`/`'false'` will always returns truthy

Comment: authenticated:{
type:Boolean,
value: false,
notify:true
}, yes , check my property

Comment: @Rahul so you should say on `{{authenticated.value}}`

Comment: check my answer.

Comment: @Rahul you could have suggest an edit to my answer as well :p

Answer (score 0):

True and False will work once you add template with in template. I tried

```
   <template>
    <template is="dom-if" if="{{authenticated}}">
        {{authenticated}}
        <p>The ID is {{controller.greeting.id}}</p>
        <p>The content is {{controller.greeting.content}}</p>
     </template>

    <template is="dom-if" if="{{!authenticated}}">
        {{authenticated}}
        <p>Login to see your greeting</p>
     </template>
    </template>
```

If you will not add template with in template True, false will never work. It will always show you the first template wheather you have True or False value of properties.

Hope it works.